# How to iterate through table and modify entrys in an "if" statement with MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, compression

What I have is a table containing some temperature readings which often jump back and forth.

```
+------------+----------+-------------+
| timestamp  | sensorID | temperature |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 1511020195 | 1        | 25          |
| 1511020196 | 1        | 26          |
| 1511020197 | 1        | 25          |
+------------+----------+-------------+
```

I'd like to iterate through the table and delete some rows if some conditions are met. Here is some pseudocode of what I am trying to do:

```
int senID = 1;
int timestamps[] = //SELECT `timestamp` FROM `temperature` WHERE `sensorID` = senID
int actentry = sizeof(timestamps);

while(actentry >= 2)
{
    int acttemp = gettemp(actentry);
    int lasttemp = gettemp(actentry-1);
    int secondlasttemp = gettemp(actentry-2);
    if(acttemp == lasttemp)
    {
        //DELETE FROM `temperature` WHERE `timestamp` = timestamps[actentry] AND `sensorID` = senID
    }
    else if((acttemp == secondlasttemp) && ((acttemp == lasttemp+1) || (acttemp == lasttemp -1)))
    {
        //DELETE FROM `temperature` WHERE `timestamp` = timestamps[actentry] AND `sensorID` = senID
        //DELETE FROM `temperature` WHERE `timestamp` = timestamps[actentry-1] AND `sensorID` = senID
    }
    actentry--;
}

int gettemp(int entry)
{
    return //SELECT `temp` FROM `temperature` WHERE `timestamp` = timestamps[entry] AND `sensorID` = senID
}
```

Is there a way of executing this directly on my MySQL DB?

I asked [before](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191230/detect-and-remove-entries-with-values-jumping-back-and-forth) but didn't get an answer. Because of that I wrote this pseudocode to give a better explanation of what I am trying to to.

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Do you have any other  questions, if not can you mark the answer as chosen?

Comment: I haven't had time to try it but I am sure it will work like this. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using? MySQL version 8 has [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) that support [`last_value()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_last-value).

Shy of using MySQL 8, you have two options,

- Write a `PROCEDURE` that uses [cursors in the database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html)
- Write a function that uses a cursor in a client side language.

My own preference, if I was to do this task in MySQL would be to write it outside of the server if that was reasonable (the data could be moved off-server), if not (we're talking about millions of rows) I would write a `PROCEDURE`

Comment: I am using version 5.5.58 and my db contains about 6 million rows. Therefore I will try your advice of using cursors in a procedure. Thank you!

Comment: MySQL 8.03 is still at rc stage - I don't think people will be rushing to put it into production!

Comment: @Vérace I trust it with any data that I would trust MySQL 7 with. ;)